# Voice Recognition предлагает дополнительные слова

Tags: java, android, распознавание-речи

Значит вопрос стоит вот как: у меня в программе используется заполнение полей голосом — нажимаем на кнопку и говорим, а дальше то, что сказал, появляется в `EditText`. Проблема в том, что мне Voice Recognition предлагает ещё дополнительные слова.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы Voice Recognition не предлагал дополнительные слова, а только то, что я сказал? Делал распознавание по [этому сайту](http://ondroid.info/raspoznaem-rech-v-android/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугл производит ранжирование наиболее подходящих слов, поэтому выводит несколько результатов наиболее похожих на сказанное выражений.

`intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5)`

В данном случае выведет 5 результатов.

Answer (score 1):

Это виноват не Voice Recognition, а настройки клавиатуры. Поставьте в своем EditText флаг `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS`